# How to split excel worksheet into multiple excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, split, worksheet

```vb
Sub SplitandFilterSheet()

Dim Splitcode As Range
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

Set Splitcode = Range("Splitcode")

For Each cell In Splitcode

Sheets("PO Line Item").Copy After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count)

Set Sheet = Worksheets(Sheets.Count)
        
        Sheet.Name = cell.Value
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value

With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(cell.Value).Range("MasterData")

.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="<>" & cell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues

.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With


ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The following VBA code can help you quickly split multiple worksheets of current workbook to separate Excel files, please do as follows:

1. Create a new folder for the workbook that you want to split, because the split Excel files will be stayed at the same folder as this master workbook.
2. Hold down the ALT + F11 keys in Excel, and it opens the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications window.
3. Click Insert > Module, and paste the following code in the Module Window.

VBS CODE //

```
Sub Splitbook()

Dim vis As Long, xPath As String, xWs As Worksheet

xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = False



For Each xWs In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

vis = xWs.Visible

xWs.Visible = xlSheetVisible

xWs.Copy

Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xPath & "\" & xWs.Name, _FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook

Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

xWs.Visible = vis
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

4. Press the F5 key to run this code. And the workbook is split to separate Excel files in the same folder with the original workbook.

Note: If one of the sheets has the same name with the workbook, this VBA cannot work.

Comment: Thanks so much.    I think this code is to split each sheets in workbook into different work book.    However, my question is to split by group.   so there is a column in the spreadsheet called "Pur Group", according to it value, 191, for example.   I like to have all 191 into one workbook.    (both sheets have the same column called "Pur Group".    I like to have 191.xlsx to have 2 sheet with only "Pur Group"=191.

Comment: so there is a column in the spreadsheet called "Pur Group", according to its value,  for example 191.   I like to have all 191 into one workbook.    (both sheets have the same column called "Pur Group".    I like to have 191.xlsx to have 2 sheet (PO LIne item & PO GRIR) with only "Pur Group"=191.